# How can I correctly align cards for different screens?

Tags: jquery, html, css, phonegap

I have a problem and is that my cards are not aligned correctly, I mean I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYrc9.png)

What I've tried was to get the position of the cards and then add the height of the card I want to move but it fails. I still get big white gaps.

Here is some of my code:

This code is in order to get the height:

```
$(".cardItem").each(function(i, item) {
      // when index is 0 then top position is 0 and left position is 0
      if (i == 0) {
         $('.mainCardHolder' + i).css('left', 0);
         $('.mainCardHolder' + i).css('position', 'static');
      }

      // when index is 1 then top position is 0 and left position is the half of the screen
      if(i == 1) {
          $('.mainCardHolder'+i).css('position', 'static');
          $('.mainCardHolder'+i).css('left', window.screen.width / 2);
      }

      // if is greater than 1 then goes the magic
      if(i > 1) {
         // Getting the final position using the top of the two previous cards and adding the height of the card I want to move
         var finalPos = $('.mainCardHolder' + (i-2)).offset().top + ($('.mainCardHolder' + (i-2)).height());
         console.log(finalPos);

         // Setting the final position to the card I move
         $('.mainCardHolder'+i).css('top', finalPos);

         // If is unpair then the left position is the half screen 
         if(i % 2 != 0) {
             var widthDividedBy2 = window.screen.width / 2;
             $('.mainCardHolder'+i).css('left', widthDividedBy2);
             $('.mainCardHolder'+i).css('position', 'static');
         }

         // If is pair then the left pos is 0
         if(i % 2 == 0) {
             $('.mainCardHolder'+i).css('left', 0);
             $('.mainCardHolder'+i).css('position', 'static');
         }
    }
});
```

The cards are added dynamically, I use materializecss for front-end and I use firebase as backend.

EDIT1: This is what i want to achieve: [Wallapop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9MCY.jpg)

Comment: Well you provided an example of the issue... what exactly are you wanting? You say "not aligned correctly" but what is the correct alignment?

Comment: Edited now you can see what i want to achieve

Comment: Awesome, That helps a lot. Now how do you determine how many columns there are? This could simply be dealt with using a vertical block layout for each column, then customizing the number of columns you put cards into and finally using modulus on the index of the card with the column of the card.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started... This is only one of many ways to do it :-)

```js
var numberOfCards = 20;
var numberOfColumns = 4;

var container = document.getElementById("container");
var columns = [];

for (var index = 0; index < numberOfColumns; index++) {
  var newColumn = document.createElement('div');
  newColumn.className = "column";
  container.appendChild(newColumn);
  columns.push(newColumn);
}

for (var index = 0; index < numberOfCards; index++) {
  var columnIndex = index % numberOfColumns;
  var newCard = document.createElement('div');
  newCard.className = "card";
  columns[columnIndex].appendChild(newCard);
  newCard.style.height = (Math.random() * 500) + 'px';
}
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

#container>.column {
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  background-color: green;
}
#container>.column>.card {
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i found the solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution in a codepen this guy has saved my life entirely

```
.cards-container {
  column-break-inside: avoid;
}
.cards-container .card {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: visible;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .cards-container {
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
    -moz-column-count: 1;
    column-count: 1;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  .cards-container {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 993px) {
  .cards-container {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
  }
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

https://codepen.io/mike-north/pen/MwVoYp

if the author of the codepen is reading this i want to say to you thanks